# Swift 3 - setting a property on an array of views

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, immutability

I was previously able to clean up my code by adding multiple views (UIImageViews, UILabels, and UIButtons) to an array and then iterating through the array to make a property change like this:

```
var hideViews = [imageView1, imageView2, label1, button1, button2]
      for eachView in hideViews {
          eachView.isHidden = true
      }
```

which then became in another version of Swift:

```
var hideViews = [imageView1, imageView2, label1, button1, button2] as [Any]
      for eachView in hideViews {
          (eachView as AnyObject).isHidden = true
      }
```

I was also able to use this to move several views at once:

```
for view in viewsToMove {
    (view as AnyObject).frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.origin.x - 30, y: view.frame.origin.y, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}
```

I am now getting the errors:

Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Bool!'

Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'CGRect!'

Does anybody know what I'm missing here, in order to do this in Swift 3?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just define the array as `var hideViews : [UIView] = [imageView1, imageView2, label1, button1, button2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isHidden` and `frame` are properties of `UIView` class so you should not cast them to `AnyObject` if you want to update properties that belong to them. Just do:

```
let views: [UIView] = [imageView1, imageView2, label1, button1, button2]

for view in views {
  view.isHidden = true
  view.frame = CGRect(x: ..., y: ...)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for being the first to answer and pointing out the array should be case to [UIView] instead of [Any] which was ultimately the problem here. Also I was going to point out the proper Swift 3 code of .isHidden instead of .hidden but you have already updated your answer. Marking this as the answer but I may also update my code to @appzYourLife answer below. I don't love using $0 in my code, but I like the .forEach structure of iterating through an array.

Answer (score 6):

Given an array of `UIView`

```
let hideViews: [UIView] = ...
```

You can **hide** each view

```
hideViews.forEach { $0.isHidden = true }
```

**move** each view 30 points to the left

```
hideViews.forEach { $0.frame.origin.x -= 30 }
```

or **both**

```
hideViews.forEach {
    $0.isHidden = true
    $0.frame.origin.x -= 30
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the ability to iterate through the array using .forEach - this is a helpful shorthand to keep in the coding toolbox!

Comment: Also much cleaner to just update the frame.origin.x value instead of the full CGRect frame as I was doing in my question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to force cast to Any or AnyObject.
This work For Swift3:

```js
let v = UIView()
let i = UIImageView()
let l = UILabel()
let b = UIButton()

// Swift auto infers array type, this is equal to write
// let views: [UIView] = [v, i, l, b]
let views = [v, i, l, b]


views.forEach {
    $0.isHidden = true
}

//or

for view in views {
    view.frame = CGRect.zero
}
```